# add link on page background

Tags: html, css

how add on page, a background with link?
On my page, I can't click on background, how fix it?

IS ONE PROBLEM, i can't change "page" class style.

```
<style>
.page{
    width: 600px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #336699;  
}
.bg_image{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image:url('bg_image.png');
    background-position:center; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        text text text ...
    </div>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <div class="bg_image" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    </a>
</body>
```

Edit:
i add sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/4sdDa/

I need add link on page background(blue page part).
When i click on background, i wish go to google.

Comment: just for knowledge never put block element inside an inline element it's a bad mark-up

Comment: Your question isn't clear... what do you want to click on ? Can you give us a link to a working HTML page? Shai.

Comment: I wish add link on my page background.

Comment: The [answer by Shai](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913667/add-link-on-page-background/7913763#7913763) looks good to me from my understanding, but you still say it's not what you want. So I ask you: What do you mean by "click on the background" ??

Comment: My reading is that lolalola wants to be able to navigate to a different page when the background of the page is clicked on. ie the background of the page acts as a link. I may be wrong too...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to click on the div inside the `A` tag.

Lets start with the fact you shouldn't (as sandeep said in the comment) put block elements inside inline elements. I would suggest having the needed background for the `A` element itself, and identifying it by a class such as "google" for the specific link.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<style>
.page{
    width: 600px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #336699;  
}

a.google{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image:url('bg_image.png');
    background-position:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; 
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        text text text ...
    </div>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="google"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for code, but he no work. I can't click on background.

Comment: Please provide a link to your example so I can check for the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript / jquery for this target:

```
$('.bg_image').click(function () {
  location.href = $(this).parent().attr("href");
});
```

This will work.
Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: It is non tested code because it is just example. You should use this way. Do you use jquery in your app?